# GDAL convert one PDF layer to tif

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdal-translate

I tried to convert one PDF layer to tiff using GDAL but the resulting tif still has all layers.
This is what I tried.

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff burglesum.pdf burglesumout.tif --config GDAL_PDF_LAYERS "Layer.Image"
```

Comment: I checked and I noticed that it worked but I was looking at the old tif I created without selecting layers. How do I close the question?